# Connecting an application program to SQL Server from another network segment

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, networking, segment

I want my vb.net application to access the sql database from another network segment.

I have two network segment, the application program that I made is in 192.168.7.xx segment and the SQL Server 2005 Enterprise Edition is in 192.168.1.xx segment but that application program cannot access the sql server unless I make them in the same segment.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

http://new-passive-income.blogspot.com

http://mbleisure.blogspot.com

Comment: This question has more to do with networking than programming.  You might get better answers over at serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

If your networks are connected by a *router* correctly configured, you should be able to access your server from another network segment. If that doesn't work, check if the gateway of your workstation and of the server is set to the network addresses of the router, maybe 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.7.1.

If your router is a linux machine, make sure packets are allowed to pass through both interfaces.